# Question about $\delta$'s meaning

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

These original photos are from Michael Spivak's ["comprehensive introduction to differential geometry"](https://kupdf.net/download/michael-spivak-a-comprehensive-introduction-to-differential-geometry-volume-2-third-edition-publish-or-perish-1999-pdf_58d816eadc0d604829c346a5_pdf).
If you look at the second picture here, In the fourth line from the top, you can see the sentence "substituting $d+\delta$ for $d$ leads also to
$
\sum_{i,j}g_{ij}dy^i\delta y^j = \sum_{i}dx^i\delta x^i
$
for arbitrary values of the $dx^i$ and $\delta x^i$ ."
But, I don't quite understand what $\delta$ means in this picture. I guess that $\delta$ is a Kronecker delta or cross product, But, I think it's very unlikely that it means cross product. which is assumed to be a symbol that converts between a contravariant vector and a covariant vector.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, $\delta$ here is not Kronecker’s delta. For Riemann, $dx^i$ is “an infinitesimal displacement in the $x^i$ direction”; in modern language, we think of it as the $1$-form $dx^i$, which for each tangent vector $\xi$, assigns the number $(dx^i)(\xi)$ (i.e it is the $i^{th}$ coefficient $\xi^i$ in the basis expansion $\xi=\sum_{j=1}^n\xi^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$).

For Riemann, $\delta x^i$ denotes an “*independent* infinitesimal displacement in the $x^i$ direction” (meaning of “independent” is explained 2 paragraphs below). In modern language we would not introduce a new symbol, we’d continue to write $dx^i$.

For Riemann, the product $dy^i\cdot dy^j$ means given an “infinitesimal displacement”, multiply the $i^{th}$ component and $j^{th}$ component. In modern language, “infinitesimal displacement” is replaced with the idea of a tangent vector $\xi$, and the product now stands for the mapping on tangent spaces given by $\xi\mapsto (dy^i)(\xi)\cdot (dy^j)(\xi)$.

But, the “independent” part means that the “product” $dy^i\delta y^j$ is, in modern terminology, actually a tensor product of the $1$-form $dy^i$ with the $1$-form $dy^j$, i.e $dy^i\otimes dy^j$. Notice that this tensor product can now eat a pair of tangent vectors $(dy^i\otimes dy^j)(\xi,\eta):=(dy^i)(\xi)\cdot (dy^j)(\eta)$. The fact that we allow for a pair of tangent vectors $\xi,\eta$ at the same point, where $\xi$ and $\eta$ have nothing to do with each other, rather than just a single vector $\xi$ to be eaten is what makes it “independent”.

So, when Riemann says “replace $d$ by $d+\delta$”, he’s really just doing the polarization identity, to convert a quadratic form to its symmetric bilinear form. Anyway, Spivak himself comments on this somewhere in the text, so just keep reading.

Comment: I'm really thank you for your answer. But I have a one more question about this. Could you explain more precisely meaning of "independent"?

Comment: @pokssin if you didn’t understand my fourth paragraph, then all I can say is the most precise way of formulating it is to forget what Riemann wrote, and just think $g_{ij}\,dy^i\otimes dy^j$.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. the tensor product in fourth paragraph is used to cross vector with vectors?

Comment: @pokssin I’m not sure what you mean. But if you’re reading Spivak then you have all the definitions necessary right in front of you (perhaps in volume I). Spivak was one of my main first sources for this material so I’m essentially repeating what he says.